# nest json data after JSON.parse become [Object]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I make json? data and use `JSON.stringify` then send to server side output like below ,  in server side with node js  after use `JSON.parse` the object in nest array can't be read become `[Object]` I can't figure why and how to solve it?

before JSON.parse

```
{
  "articleArticleDataList":
  [
    {
      "type":0,
      "articleDataList":
      [
        {
        "type":1,
        "name":"",
        "introduction":"",
        "description":""
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
}
```

after

```
{
 articleArticleDataList: 
 [ 
  {
   type: 0, 
   articleDataList: 
   [Object] 
  } 
 ] 
}
```

eg
this is some part how I make the data  make array then loop make object and push object into array

```
..
articleArticleData.articleDataList = [];

$.each($(this).find('.ArticleDataList .ArticleData'), function(ii, val) {
  var articleData = {};
  articleData.type = parseInt($(this).attr('data-type'));
  ...
  articleArticleData.articleDataList.push(articleData);
```

Comment: How are you getting the output in the `after` section?  It looks like what the REPL does to elide deeply-nested objects, so they don't become unreadable.

Comment: append to new FormData(); does that means I can't nest data over three level  ??

Comment: No, how are you getting that string.  `console.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`util.inspec()` is your friend.

```
var util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(json, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: thanks,  it work!!    does that means the this is the nodejs problem not my data format wrong  ?

Comment: Your data format is ok, actually  {
        "type":1,
        "name":"",
        "introduction":"",
        "description":""
        } is an object. Simply, if a data structure is too deeply nested, Node.js stops showing the details. It`s all about displaying data, not the data itself. Accept please, my answer. :)